# Socket connecting ODDLY when I add more items to each socket client

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, sockets, websocket

I am making a simple HTML5 game where upon socket connection, the server sends a packet of initialization info that would generate objects for each client, specifically, a list of tiles, players, and misc objects.

When I call **socket.emit("init", initPacket())**, the packet sent would instantiate new JS objects on the client end (that are defined on the client).

Right now the objects are instantiated fine if my server only has 1000 tiles. However, the moment I go to 1001 or 1002 tiles, or any more than that, the server will make the initPacket, attempt to emit it via the method above, and somehow **CREATE A NEW SOCKET**, and try to call **socket.emit("init", initPacket())** upon that. Also odd is that the previous socket does not disconnect (as I logged if a user disconnects).

Here are screenshots of what should happen when a client connects and disconnects VERSUS what happens if I have too many tiles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOiML.jpg

What **specifically** is causing the infinite loop? I'm assuming downgrading the initPacket so it sends less data would make it better, but I need to first find the root cause.

For reference, using Node.js and socket.io for the websocket. I open a new client whenever I open a new localhost to the correct port number.

For initPacket():

```js
var initPacket = function () {
    var ret = {};
    var playerPacket = [];
    var tilePacket = [];

    for (var i in PLAYER_LIST) {
        var currPlayer = PLAYER_LIST[i];
        playerPacket.push({
            id: currPlayer.id,
            name: currPlayer.name,
            x: currPlayer.x,
            y: currPlayer.y
        })
    }


    for (var j = 0; j < TILE_ARRAY.length; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < TILE_ARRAY[j].length; k++) {
            var currTile = TILE_ARRAY[j][k];
            tilePacket.push({
                id: currTile.id,
                x: currTile.x,
                y: currTile.y,
                length: currTile.length,
                color: currTile.color
            });
            count ++;
        }
    }

   
    ret['tilePacket'] = tilePacket;
    ret['playerPacket'] = playerPacket;
    
    return ret;
};
```

BASICALLY, the socket is emitting a dictionary with key of 'tilePacket' and value of a list of tile information for each tile.

TILE_ARRAY is a 2-d array of Tile Objects, which I defined here:

```js
const entityConfig = require('./entityConfig');

function Tile(x, y) {
    var randomId = Math.random();
    this.id = randomId;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.owner = null;
    this.color = "#FFFFFF";
    this.health = 0;
    this.length = entityConfig.WIDTH / Math.sqrt(entityConfig.TILES);
}


module.exports = Tile;
```

**EDIT:** to clarify, if I remove the **ret['tilePacket'] = tilePacket;** line above, the server does not loop sockets anymore. I have logged the count of items in the TILE_ARRAY for-loop and it gives me back 1024 items, which is 32 x 32, which is correct. The playerpackets here do not matter in terms of the bug.

Comment: Could you provide the code and some test data? Not the complete 1000, but a few records. Thanks.

Comment: First, please include code if you'd like us to help. Second, you're calling `socket.emit("init", initPacket())` - the second parameter for `emit` is a **function**, so unless `initPacket` returns a function, remove the `()`.